# Can't access the second of element of list of size 3

Tags: python

I have this piece of code where I try to iterate through a text file that looks like this:

[image]

```
file = open("a.txt", "r")

matrix = file.readlines()

n = matrix[0]
matrix.pop(0)

for item in matrix:
    line = item.split(', ', 2)
    #print(line[1])
    print(len(line))
    print(type(line))
```

The problem appears when I try to access line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZDL.png) or line[2], I receive the 'list out of range' error.
I checked and line is indeed a list and has size 3, and if I print line[0] it works as it should.

Comment: You also need to pop the second line, since it's a blank line and is also redundant. The data you want to parse starts from the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you are trying to split each line based on `,` and for that, you need 3 elements in each line. try with ***removing the first 2 lines*** it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're trying to parse CSV file, and try to use csv module:

```
import csv

with open('you_file.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    lines = [line[2] for line in enumerate(csv_reader) if n >= 2]
print(lines)
```

or if not sure about how many blank/unnecessary lines will be first:

```
lines = [line[1] for line in csv_reader if len(line) > 1]
```